# What does this active record query do?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am working on a existing project whose code is written by earlier developer. When I read a function in the model it was written:

```
        $this->db->select('1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('product');     
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
```

I am wondering what does this first statement does? i.e $this->db->select('1', FALSE); because there is no column named 1 in the product table. I searched online but there is no help. 
Would any explain?

Comment: What does the db object do? Specially the select() of the db object?

Comment: I know it is _selecting_ the column but the column named 1 does not exist in product table and code is running fine i.e there is no 'Unknown column 1 in the product table' error.

Comment: There must be an object define in you code. It isn't any standard php function. Please check which object is in $this->db and copy us the select() function of this object class.

Comment: it looks like a small checking query that isn't designed to pass back information using the `$query->result_array();` the 1 in the SELECT is just used so that it isn't getting all fields from the table (saving bandwidth/resources).

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't seen anything like that so far, I would do a

```
 echo $this->db->last_query()
```

after the `$this->db->get()` just to see the actual sql query for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 FROM
```

It is used to determine the existence of a result. It will return a column of 1's for every row in the result.

Comment: Isn't it being determined from num_rows()==1 ?

Comment: No as it can return more than 1 row dependent on the full query and what is in your database. However I would guess that you would have at least only one product matching. num_rows() is just checking that there is only one result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1;
```

=> 1

```
SELECT 1 + 1;
```

=> 2

Codeigniter  you can use this query when

```
$this->db->select('1', FALSE);
```

If you don't turn it to FALSE, you can only select columns

```
$this->db->select('column', TRUE);
```